# AWS Lamda + AWS API Gateway + Google Calendar API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

i'm trying to integrate these service (AWS Lamda + AWS API Gateway + Google Calendar API)
but unable to authorize the user, below is the code that i have been working with

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        credentials = None

        # Set up Google Calendar API credentials
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
        CLIENT_ID = "79909369090-rnir5ra7hd79908d7k1eedt9bns39a4v.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        CLIENT_SECRET = "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"
        REDIRECT_URI = ["http://localhost"]
        TOKEN_FILE = 'token.json'

        # Check if the token file exists
        # if os.path.exists(TOKEN_FILE):
        #     # Load existing token from the file
        #     flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
        #     credentials = flow.credentials
        if True:
            # Create a new token
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(
                {
                    'installed': {
                        'client_id': "",
                        'project_id': "",
                        'auth_uri': "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                        'token_uri': "",
                        'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': "",
                        'client_secret': "",
                    'redirect_uris': [""]
                    }
                },
                SCOPES
            )

            # Run the authorization flow in the console
            auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')
            print('Please go to this URL and authorize the application: ')
            print(auth_url)
            auth_code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
            flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=auth_code)

            # Save the token to a file for future use
            credentials = flow.credentials
            with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'w') as token:
                token.write(credentials.to_json())

        # Create a new instance of the Calendar API
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        # Get the next event from the user's calendar
        now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
        events_result = service.events().list(
            calendarId='email',
            timeMin=now,
            maxResults=1,
            singleEvents=True,
            orderBy='startTime'
        ).execute()

        events = events_result.get('items', [])

        if not events:
            response = {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': 'No upcoming events found.'
            }
        else:
            next_event = events[0]
            event_summary = next_event['summary']
            event_start = next_event['start'].get('dateTime', next_event['start'].get('date'))
            event_end = next_event['end'].get('dateTime', next_event['end'].get('date'))

            response = {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': {
                    'summary': event_summary,
                    'start': event_start,
                    'end': event_end
                }
            }

        return response

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error retrieving next event:', e)
        response = {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': 'An error occurred while retrieving the next event.'
        }
        return response
```

Comment: Your code has calls to `input()`. AWS Lambda functions cannot interact with a user. They need to be provided everything at invocation time, or through configuration or runtime lookup when executing.